# Windows MySQL Service keeps starting despite being told to stop

Tags: mysql, windows, service

I have a problem with MySQL Server 5.5.11 (64-bit) running on Windows Server 2008 (64 bit).

I made a fresh install, selecting default options and installing it as a service on Windows. Everything works perfectly when the server is running. The server is then setup as slave to a master server.

Since this server is a slave-server I want to occasionally take it down to make a backup of the database (helpful tips of how to do hot-backup is not needed :)).

**I use "NET STOP MYSQL" command and the server stops.**

**THE PROBLEM: A few minutes after the server stops it automatically starts again! Without any command issued (by me that I know of) to do so!**

Checking in Windows Services I saw it was set as startup type "automatic" but I have also tried setting it to manual - it still restarts after a few minutes. There are no errors in the MySQL-error log. I see the shutdown complete message and then ~2 minutes later the normal messages that I get when the server starts up.

Anyone know of any other setting that makes MySQL Service automatically restart on Windows?

EDIT: culprit found.. motive unknown: It is the Service Control Manager that keeps restarting the service according to the event viewer. What triggers it to start the service is however still unkown.

EDIT 2: Removed and reinstalled the service and it keeps restarting despite being told to stop.

Comment: Are there any dependencies listed for this service (services.msc > MySQL > Properties > Dependendy tab)?

Comment: are there any scheduled tasks to start every few minutes?

Comment: No, no dependencies. Both fields are empty.

Comment: No scheduled tasks either - furthermore I've checked sheduled tasks that completed in the last hour of a MySQL server stop and automatic start and no tasks where reported to have completed during that time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was a monitoring service by our hosting partner that "helped" us by automatically starting services that (they thought) where supposed to be running.

I found this clue using netstat and seeing an unkown computer being constantly connected to the server.